# How can we connect to Apache Ignite which is deployed on Openshift Docker as image?

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, ignite

We are trying to connect apache ignite which is deployed on openshift docker, can anyone help how can we connect or integrate this using java or spring ?

Comment: Plese clarify, do you want to connect to an Ignite cluster deployed on OpenShift from outside?

Comment: yes : alexfedotov

Comment: @alexfedotov 2  yes we are trying to connect the ignite cluster from outside.

Comment: I think the following approaches can be used:
1. Docker host mode networking. This mode effectively disables network isolation of a Docker container. `sudo docker run -it --net=host` please see this page for details https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/docker-deployment
2. configuring the mapping between external and internal addresses. It can be done via AddressResolver. There is BasicAddressResolver that is provided by Ignite out of the box. https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.1.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/BasicAddressResolver.html